# Does Plastic SCM work with (play nice) gitKracken?

Tags: gitkraken, plasticscm

evaluating if PSCM is right for my team. Team is concerned about changing how they work with code and are understandably reluctant to stop using GitKracken, artists want PLSCM and Gluon.

nothing. asking before buying.

na

na

Answer (score 0):

I'm the founder at Plastic SCM, so I think I can give you a good answer about how we interop with Git.

Well, fist it is worth saying that Plastic is not based on Git. It is a full version control stack, we developed it from the ground up.

Our secret sauce is that we can do a bunch of things that Git can't, or at least that's what we try. Things like good handling of file locks, big files, ability to work not only distributed (Git style) but centralized, and a few others.

That being said, it is not our goal to have developers using tools like GitKraken on top of Plastic, because basically we develop our own GUIs, and most importantly, because GitKraken is heavily dependent on the underlying Git commands and libraries, which are not compatible with how Plastic works.

So: while it might take some time initially, we really prefer if developers try to use Plastic GUIs.

There is a workaround, though: every Plastic on-premises server can act as a Git server. So you can use GitKraken on top of Git, then push/pull to Plastic. Not our favorite way of working since then developers miss many of the advantages in Plastic.

Hope it helps and do not hesitate to ask more questions :-)

pablo